# Define a kind of macros or functions in SQLite to stop copying same request over and over

Tags: sqlite, function, macros

Here is the context, I use SQLite to store application's data that contain many parameters and some of them can be translated in several languages.

To do so, I've defined a table named *Message* which contains all of the translations. Each message is identified by a unique index and each parameter that have to display translated strings are linked to the table *Message*.

For example, I have a table named *ObdParameter* which contains all of the OBD parameters my application can read and some fields of this table are translated in several languages, e.g (*OdbParameter.Name*, *OdbParameter.Description*, *OdbParameter.Help*).

If I want to select all of the OBD parameters stored in the database I use the following SQLite request. (Only the parameters' identifiers and names are selected).

```
SELECT o.IdObdParameter,
COALESCE( NULLIF( trim( m.Message ), '' ), mDef.Message, '' ) AS Name
FROM ObdParameter o
-- JOINTURE on the name
LEFT JOIN Message m ON m.IdString=o.IdName AND m.CodeLanguage='ENG'
LEFT JOIN Message mDef ON mDef.IdString=o.IdName AND mDef.CodeLanguage='FRE'
ORDER BY Name;
```

With this request, SQLite joins the english translation to *ObdParameter.IdName* but if there's no english translation, it also joins the french translation (which is the default language) and if finally there's no french translation it returns an empty string.

This is very handy but it make the request complicated to read.

For example If I want to select all of the OBD parameters with their descriptions and associated helps I have to write the request below.

```
SELECT o.IdObdParameter,
COALESCE( NULLIF( trim( m.Message ), '' ), mDef.Message, '' ) AS Name
COALESCE( NULLIF( trim( m1.Message ), '' ), m1Def.Message, '' ) AS Description
COALESCE( NULLIF( trim( m2.Message ), '' ), m2Def.Message, '' ) AS Help
FROM ObdParameter o
-- JOINTURE on the name
LEFT JOIN Message m ON m.IdString=o.IdName AND m.CodeLanguage='ENG'
LEFT JOIN Message mDef ON mDef.IdString=o.IdName AND mDef.CodeLanguage='FRE'
-- JOINTURE on the descritpion
LEFT JOIN Message m1 ON m1.IdString=o.IdDescription AND m1.CodeLanguage='ENG'
LEFT JOIN Message m1Def ON m1Def.IdString=o.IdDescription AND m1Def.CodeLanguage='FRE'
-- JOINTURE on the help
LEFT JOIN Message m2 ON m2.IdString=o.IdHelp AND m2.CodeLanguage='ENG'
LEFT JOIN Message m2Def ON m2Def.IdString=o.IdHelp AND m2Def.CodeLanguage='FRE'
ORDER BY Name;
```

It works very well.

But I was wondering if there's a way to define a kind of macros or function so I could write the previous request as:

```
SELECT o.IdObdParameter,
GET_TRANSLATION( m ) AS Name
GET_TRANSLATION( m1 ) AS Description
GET_TRANSLATION( m2 ) AS Help
FROM ObdParameter o
-- JOINTURE on the name
JOIN_TRANSLATION( m, o.IdName, 'ENG', 'FRE' )
-- JOINTURE on the descritpion
JOIN_TRANSLATION( m1, o.IdDescription , 'ENG', 'FRE' )
-- JOINTURE on the help
JOIN_TRANSLATION( m2, o.IdHelp, 'ENG', 'FRE' )
ORDER BY Name;
```

Which is much simpler to read and to use.

Do SQLite support this feature ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in any DBMS. If at all this would be a client side feature - your SQL client tool will need to expand the "JOIN_TRANSLATION()" macro to valid SQL. You could make things easier if you create a view for each language then you could do a `JOIN v_en_messages ON ...`. I don't know SQLite but if it supports `NATURAL JOIN` and you name the columns in the view properly, you can also get rid of putting the join columns in there (but I wouldn't recommend that for production code, only for ad-hoc queries)

Comment: Views are not exactly what I need cause I also have to select OBD parameters by filtering them (e.g. `WHERE ObdParameter.LocalCode=5`) so I won't create a view for all possible filters. There's many others tables in the database.

Comment: I will have a look at the function [sqlite3_create_function()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html)...

Answer (score 0):

There are databases that can generate dynamic SQL inside stored procedures, but SQLite is an embedded database; it is designed to be used as part of an application that is written in a 'real' programming language.

You have to implement this functionality in your application.

An embedded database has no client/server communication overhead; you could just use three queries to read the three values.

Comment: I know SQLite does not support stored procedures cause it's client/server database engine, that's why I  was wondering whereas a workaround was available.